# How to make nodejs telegram bot to get in row of sertain queries?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

I tried to find some answer for this, but got nothing relative. I need to implement something like form as row of Q&A, for example:
U: /form
B: Enter your name
U: John
B: Hello, John. Are you 12 years old?
...
and so on. And I'm going to write answers in Google Spreadsheets, but there's no problem, I just don't know how to create a chain on phrases with bot

Thanks for attention

Comment: The community is here to help you, but you need to ask good questions that show your work, what you have tried and where you are stuck. Please give these a good read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask & https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the basis of my answer is on a Node library I use for making telegram bots in all my projects. It's called [telegram-node-bot](https://github.com/Naltox/telegram-node-bot), the way other libraries would do it will differ but I like this method cause it lifts all of the heavy load for me and easy to understand.

Here we go:

```
const Telegram = require('telegram-node-bot');
const TelegramBaseController = Telegram.TelegramBaseController;
const TextCommand = Telegram.TextCommand;
const tg = new Telegram.Telegram('YOUR_TOKEN'); //Ask botfather for your token

class FormController extends TelegramBaseController {
    /**
     * @param {Scope} $
     */
    formHandler($) {
        const form = {
          name: {
            q: 'Send me your name',
            error: 'Sorry, wrong input',
            validator: (message, callback) => {
              const answer = message.text;

              if (answer) { 
                callback(true, answer);
                return
              }

              callback(false);
            }
          },
          age: {
            q: 'Send me your age',
            error: 'sorry, wrong input',
            validator: (message, callback) => {
              const answer = message.text;

              if (answer && IsNumeric(answer)) {
                callback(true, toInt(answer))
                return
              }

              callback(false)
            }
          }
      }

      $.runForm(form, (result) => {
        console.log(result)
      })
    }

    get routes() {
        return {
            'formCommand': 'formHandler'
        }
    }
}

tg.router
    .when(
        new TextCommand('/form', 'formCommand'),
        new FormController()
    )
```

The logic/algorithm behind it is simple:

1. Ask a question.
2. Wait for a response.
3. Check if the response fits the criterias you've set for the right answer format
4. If false ask the question again.
5. If true move to the next question.